# How can I select the proper output format for service starttime query?

Tags: powershell

Forgive the PS noob question. I am struggling thru self learning PowerShell scripting. I finally got this remote command syntax corrected. The objective is to see a service up time on a remote server. I changed the server name and service name for this example. Here is the command –

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server {New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Process winlogon).StartTime}
```

to which I get this sample output –

```
Days : 0
Hours : 12
Minutes : 49
Seconds : 20
Milliseconds : 850
Ticks : 461608503901
TotalDays : 0.534269101737268
TotalHours : 12.8224584416944
TotalMinutes : 769.347506501667
TotalSeconds : 46160.8503901
TotalMilliseconds : 46160850.3901
PSComputerName : servername
```

All of this information is fine, but too much for my purposes. All I want is the days, hours minutes, and PSComputername. I am not interested in writing this output to a file. I just want the details at a higher level. What do I need to add to the command to get the desired output?

I appreciate your attention
Shoop

Comment: `.. | select Days, Hours, Minutes, PSComputerName`  ? Your title asks for the 'proper output format' but you haven't said what format you consider proper...

Comment: I would like the output to be similar to my example above, but only with the aforementioned fields. When I the pipe command with the select options, I get the output in a horizontal line rather that was is seen here. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, use `select` to specify which properties you want

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server `
{New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Process winlogon).StartTime} `
| select Days, Hours, Minutes, PSComputerName
```

You can also do a "select as" by using this syntax

```
select @{l='days';e='Days'}, @{l='hours';e='Hours'}
```

which would change the property name for you. e.g. "Days" now is "days"

Lastly, you can store in a variable and access specific properties

```
$output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName server `
{New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Process winlogon).StartTime} `
| select Days, Hours, Minutes, PSComputerName
```

Get properties by:

`$output.Days`

You can store this in a custom object as well, I just don't have enough information about how you want the output.

Comment: As mentioned above - when I the pipe command with the select options, I get the output in a horizontal line rather that my example. I append this information to a status log file that gets sent out.

The layout for the output example I provided is what I want, but I only want the fields mentioned.

Comment: @Shoop61 if you want vertical output `$var = Invoke-Command ...` then do `foreach($row in $var) { echo $row }`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Getting errors when I try that. I may have the syntax wrong.    $var = Invoke-Command -ComputerName hostname {New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Process winlogon).StartTime} | select Days, Hours, Minutes, PSComputername $foreach($row in $var) { echo $row }

Comment: The foreach should be on a different line. And there's no `$` before the foreach

Comment: Running that i get this output which is basically the same thing I got when using the first command -  
Days      Hours     Minutes PSComputerName                        
----         -----            ------- --------------                        
   0           13                 26 hostname

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Servername {New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Process 'Servicename').StartTime | select Days, Hours, Minutes, PSComputerName}
```

Comment: This did answer the question.